# Problems Using Azure Functions v3 to send messages to the Azure Notification Hub, with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-notificationhub

I'm getting an error which I can't seem to debug when attempting to create an azure function to send a message to the notification hub.

Specifically, when I'm trying to run the section [C# script template example - asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs#c-script-template-example---asynchronous). the document  refers to a function.json that is generated when I'm building this, but unfortunately I don't get this under vs2019. I stored my settings in local.settings.json. executing the snippet results in an error:

```
[2021-01-20T19:31:16.751Z] Found C:\AnhExp\AnhExp.Function02\AnhExp.Function02.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2021-01-20T19:31:19.066Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'ANHMessage02'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'notification' to type IAsyncCollector`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-01-20T19:31:19.133Z] Error indexing method 'ANHMessage02'
[2021-01-20T19:31:19.136Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'ANHMessage02'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'notification' to type IAsyncCollector`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2021-01-20T19:31:19.138Z] Function 'ANHMessage02' failed indexing and will be disabled.
[2021-01-20T19:31:19.171Z] The 'ANHMessage02' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'ANHMessage02'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'notification' to type IAsyncCollector`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
```

the error seems to indicate that it can't bind properly, but I'm not sure which libraries to add or to describe the binding with.

AnhMessage02 has this header:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;

...

[FunctionName("ANHMessage02")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            IAsyncCollector<IDictionary<string, string>> notification,
            ILogger log)
```

and my local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsNotificationHubsConnectionString": "Endpoint=?;SharedAccessKeyName=?;SharedAccessKey=?"
  },
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "notificationHub",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "notification",
      "tagExpression": "",
      "hubName": "?",
      "connection": "Endpoint=?;SharedAccessKeyName=?;SharedAccessKey=?",
      "platform": "apns"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification Hubs output binding for Azure Functions is just available in Azure Function 1.x and is not available in Functions 2.x and higher. For more details, please refer to [the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs#packages---functions-1x)
[image]

For example

1. Install SDk

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.NotificationHubs -Version 1.3.0
```

2. Configurate connection string

local.setting.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "<language worker>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connection-string>",
    "MyHubConnectionString": "<the connection string for the hub>",
  
  },
}
```

2. Code

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,[NotificationHub(ConnectionStringSetting= "MyHubConnectionString", EnableTestSend =true,HubName ="hub")] IAsyncCollector<IDictionary<string, string>> notification, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }
            Dictionary<string, string> templateProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            templateProperties["user"] = "A new user wants to be added : " + name;
            await notification.AddAsync(templateProperties);
            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @jim-xu  . I did read that statement, and noticed it was odd that there were still all kinds of examples showing the implementation using v2+. How were they implemented then?

Comment: @soler Could you please provide the document you refer to?

Comment: hi @jim-xu, it's at [C# script template example - asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs#c-script-template-example---asynchronous). I'm wondering if I misunderstood the text and assumed that just because it's below 2.x that it's for that particular version. I was able to use notification hub in my local example by embedding the actual call (i.e. without the `IAsyncCollector<>` parameter), just thought that being fed to the collector makes the function less imperative

Comment: @soler According to the document, the binding is just can be used into the Net framework function. The Net Framework function is Azure function V1. For more details, pleas refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#supported-versions

Comment: Tks @jim-xu. I think you're right and I'll be sticking to my implementation without using iasynccollector